# Posibilidad de borrar particion recuperacion Windows10 sin problemas

Tags: windows10, windows11

al pasar a la versión de Windows11 veo que se creó una partición de recuperación que está entre mi disco C y otra partición D con más tamaño. Al necesitar Windows 11 mas tamaño y por instalación de más programas descubro que necesito ampliar el tamaño del disco C pero lo impide la partición de recuperación que se creó al pasar a Windows 11.

La pregunta es: ¿puedo eliminar la partición de recuperación sin que me dé algún tipo de problema en el futuro? He visto tutoriales de cómo hacerlo pero no estoy seguro si hago bien.

Otra pregunta sería:¿hay algún modo de mover dicha partición de recuperación detrás del disco C para que no de problemas para aumentar el tamaño del disco C reducir el de D?

Si ninguna de las 2 opciones fuera correcta podrían ofrecerme alguna alternativa para solucionar este problema?

Gracias por su ayuda